# What is the term for a person that feels the urge to read everything?

Tags: terminology

It seems there could be more than one term, to describe different flavors of this urge:

1. The urge to read may stem from inherent curiosity, so **"bookworm"** may fit. It is not precise enough because the feeling may extend not just to books, but also newspapers, journals, educational material, Q&A on Stack Exchange, etc.
2. A kind of **"mania"**, for example a person that can't ignore advertisements, posters, or any other form of random text that catches the eye.

Comment: Mad reader, I say

Comment: Some sort of logomania/verbomania considering he is only interested in worded materials

Comment: '-mania' has a compulsive flavor, while '-philia' feels less so. ***Lexiphile / lexophile***, maybe?

Comment: Forget my suggestion. I'd go with what @JimMack said. " Mania" is a tad too extreme.

Comment: a -philia term will fit the first definition, a -mania term for the second. I'm looking for a nomenclature for both an enlightened, avid reader (as proposed) and a compulsive reader, for which I'd expect some professional term. Is it only expressible by adjectives?

Comment: a person who reads everything is a lectorphile

Comment: @Lambie - what is the etymology of lectorphile? Is it from English? I googled the term and was very surprised to see 18 results only, with one of them clearly showing the meaning (which was spot on): ["or even— lectorphile that I am— reading at night without a candle fit"](http://read.dukeupress.edu/content/who-counts.body.pdf‏)

Comment: Google is not a writer. Not everything can be googled (thank goodness) and one can make up terms. This one is out there just a few times, but the "etymology" is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I am not trying to be funny, but perhaps simply **a reader** since one definition at [cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reader) includes this aspect (emphasis is mine below)

> : someone who reads for pleasure, **especially a person who reads a lot:**
>
> *He's a great/voracious reader (= reads many books).
>   She's an avid reader of historical novels.She's a very keen reader - she devours one book after another.
>   He's a voracious reader of historical novels.*

Comment: Reader, yes, but "voracious reader" says it all.  IMO, that is exactly what someone who reads everything in sight can be described.

Answer (score 1):

A **"compulsive reader"**(simple as that) comes to mind.  Not necessarily an OCD but it may reach such extremes.

> I was a compulsive reader when I was younger. I often found myself reading posters and advertisements... nothing escaped me.

Answer (score 0):

Would an "avid reader" work for you?

> #### Avid - Dictionary.com
>
> Showing great enthusiasm for or interest in.
>
> Source link: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/avid

---

> #### Avid -  Merriam-Webster.com
>
> 1) Desirous to the point of greed : urgently eager : greedy
>
> 2) Characterized by enthusiasm and vigorous pursuit.
>
> Source link: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avid

Answer (score 0):

**Bibliophile** is also listed in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bibliophile) as:

a lover of books especially for qualities of format; also:  a book collector

Which lists synonyms such as bibliolator, **bibliomaniac**, and bookman.